# Alternative to strtotime() in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have an `EventSet` table with those fields:

- `start_day` (*ex. Monday*)
- `start_time` (*ex. 14:20:00*)

I want to create a query that selects specific records by comparing their day an time with the current ones.

So, using a little help from the PHP's `strtotime();` method I am aiming at something similar to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   `EventSet` 
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%W %H:%i:%s') <= 
    date('%W %H:%i:%s', strtotime('start_day start_time'))
```

*The last `date();` part is of course pure PHP*

So far I've tried using `DATE_FORMAT` with `CONCAT_WS` and also `TIMESTAMP();` / `UNIX_TIMESTAMP();` but am clearly messing something up.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    `EventSet` 
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%W %H:%i:%s') <= 
    DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', start_day, start_time), '%W %H:%i:%s')
```

I've looked through many similar questions here and in the net, but they all already have a date field to work with and there's no need to concatenate anything, so I can't use any of them.

Comment: what is a type of start_time - time or string?

Comment: @splash58 both are strings. I can also use the week number, I have it in the table, too

Comment: `SELECT .*  FROM EventSet  WHERE WEEKDAY(NOW()) <= $start_dayNum AND TIME(NOW())) <= TIME($start_time)` function Weekday() returns 0 for Monday and so on. So you should change due to format of dayweek number in your db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `<=`.  This is not going to work for the names of the days of the week, so split the logic into two parts:  one for the day of the week and the other for the time:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM `EventSet` e
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%W') = $start_day AND
      DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s') <= DATE_FORMAT($start_time, '%H:%i:%s')
```

Note:  I left the `date_format()` in for the time comparisons,  I prefer:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM `EventSet` e
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%W') = $start_day AND
      TIME(NOW())) <= TIME($start_time)
```

Comment: Ahh, so much cleaner, thanks! I've added an extended solution based on your approach to cover all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gordon Linoff's and @spash58's solutions I've a working code now.

I'm however extending the query a bit in order to make the time dependent of the day:

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

$todayObject = new \DateTime();
$weekDay = $todayObject->format('N') - 1; // 0 - Monday; 6 - Sunday

$sql = "
    SELECT 
        start_day,
        start_time
    FROM
        EventSet
    WHERE 
        is_active = 1 AND 
        (
            WEEKDAY(NOW()) < start_day OR
            ( 
                WEEKDAY(NOW()) = start_day AND 
                TIME(NOW()) <= TIME(start_time)
            )
        )

    ORDER BY start_day ASC
    LIMIT 1                                    
";

$st = $conn->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();

$data = $st->fetchAll();
```

The `start_date` field is now converted to INT instead of string to ease the comparing. If the current week day is less than the `start_day` I don't really care about the time. Otherwise I include it in the condition.